# How to raise a boost::signal whenever a packet is recieved?

Tags: boost, boost-asio, boost-signals

I know that boost.asio has a mechanism that calls a callback function whenever a packet is received but is there an option to emit a signal instead?
Do I have to write a function that emits the signal?
If it is so, why?

Answer (score -1):

You could use a Boost.Phoenix function as your handler and have it raise the signal. I am not aware of anything built into Boost.Asio to raise a boost::signal.

Comment: Why Boost.Phoenix I'm reading the docs and I can't really understand what is it about?